# Where is an instruction sheet for Ausini set 25418 guitar?

Tags: building, instructions, clone-brands

I bought an Ausini brick set AUS-25418, which is a guitar, however as cheap as it was the price, it didn't have the building instructions, at least it looks like no piece bags or stickers are missing.

Does anyone happened to have those around? I would really appreciate any picture you could send me.

Here is a picture of the model:

[image]

I Googled for them for some days and send messages to a distributor but never received a reply. I even tried to build it from pictures of the finished model with no success.

Answer (score 3):

***Attack on the Clones: The Purist Punch-Back!***

I'm posting up these clone brick instructions at the very bottom below, but I'm going further by offering a *[free digital instruction file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e1HLOlOcdHqEEwHZPi955nTl7O-4E7HS)* to build this model with official *LEGO* bricks through *Bricklink.com* instead.

This model has 3 pieces that aren't direct clones,so they don't exist in *LEGO*, but we can easily use alternative pieces and make their need a non-issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

1. *2 x 2 plate with Inverted Studs.*
2. *2 x 2 1/3 Curve Top Brick.*
3. *Roof Tile 2 x 2 x 2/3 Plate.*

The only left over issues are the stickers (the "wow" text, blue flame effects), and the screen printed 2x4 black tile, which represents the six round yellow tuning pegs on the headstock of the guitar. I haven't looked for equivalent official *LEGO* ones, which may or may not exist.

I just used an alternate build to replace all printed art that came with this set.

[image]

These clone knock-off brands are straight up shameless.  It would be just to reverse their blasphemy, knock them off financially, and offer plans to their designs in official *LEGO* for free.

I wouldn't mind finding the most interesting/popular *Clone Brands*, and just go to town on them. I realize in most cases it will be more expensive, but at least there will be an alternative for the purist who might be less inclined to patronize these clone pirates.

---

[image]

[image]