# 2x2x2 cube with smooth plate on bottom?

Tags: piece-information, design

I have a follow-up to [my previous question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/13430/6x6x6-cube-with-smooth-plates-on-bottom) about building a 6x6x6 smooth-sided cube.

Do these three pieces create a 2x2x2 cube, smooth on top and bottom, and all four sides, with the height exactly the same as the width and the length?

- [2x2 tile (3068a)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3068a&name=Tile%202%20x%202%20without%20Groove&category=%5BTile%5D#T=C)
- [2x2 block (3003)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3003#T=C)
- [2x2 modified, inverted (11203)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11203#T=C)

For completeness, can someone provide a sketch?

AFOL, returning to the LEGO universe. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. 1x1 Brick dimensions are 5x5x6 units. 1x1 Plate/Tile dimensions are 5x5x2 units. Since we have the top surface measured 2x2 studs, this brings us to top with 10x10 units in size. From here we need to construct a side of 10 units too. Taking out top and bottom tiles (10-2-2) we are left with 6 units, which is exactly a height of a brick.

Here's an example:

[image]